# ¿Por qué en diversos textos y frases, 'diablo' terminó por imponerse sobre 'demonio'?

Tags: historia, sustantivos

En el diccionario de autoridades, *demonio* significa *"Lo mismo que diablo"* (sic) y aunque la respuesta surge de inmediato con base en las acepciones de cada término en el diccionario actual (6 acepciones y 15 frases para *[demonio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CAFACdU)* contra 9 acepciones y más de 50 frases para *[diablo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DdJ72P9)*), revisando en [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diablo%2Cdemonio&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdiablo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdiablo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDiablo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDIABLO%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdemonio%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdemonio%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDemonio%3B%2Cc0), hacia 1800 la diferencia era muy favorable a *demonio*, hace unos 100 años se igualan los términos y se termina imponiendo *diablo*. Si bien desde el CORDE aparece el término *diablo* más mencionado que demonio en el siglo XIX, durante el siglo de oro y posteriores (Siglo XVI y XVII) el CORDE muestra que aparecen el doble de *demonios* que de *diablos* escritos.En la actualidad hablamos de pobres diablos, se está con un humor de mil diablos, las cosas quedan donde el diablo dejó el poncho (o el chaleco) y otras tantas frases ¿Qué causó que se fuera imponiendo el término *diablo* en el habla cotidiana y en los diversos textos como muestra el CORDE y en Ngrams?

Comment: Curioso que, según el DLE, ambas voces provienen de sendas palabras del latín tardío (_daemonĭum_ y _diabŏlus_), y estas a su vez de sendas palabras del griego bizantino (_daimónion_ y _diábolos_). Si ambas palabras tienen la misma antigüedad no hay ninguna razón a priori para que una se imponga sobre la otra, así que ha tenido que ser el uso que le ha dado la gente.

Comment: Como apunte, eso de "imponerse" no es algo general. Aquí en España, por ejemplo, se usa más "demonio". Es posible que el cambio de tendencia tenga que ver con las diferencias poblacionales.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [publicación #133, Volumen 34 de Instituto de Teología Fundamental (Facultad de Teología de Cataluña)](http://www.seleccionesdeteologia.net/selecciones/llib/vol34/133/133_alvarez.pdf) diablo y demonio no son la misma cosa.

> **Qué es un demonio**
>
> La palabra "demonio" es de origen griego. Daimónion no es ni masculino ni femenino,
> sino neutro. No se trata, pues, de una persona, sino de una cosa. Además es un adjetivo
> sustantivado. Indica, por tanto, la personificación de una entidad abstracta. La
> mentalidad popular había creado este vocablo para designar poderes impersonales,
> potencias espirituales o fuerzas maléficas, capaces de entrar en las personas y
> provocarles enfermedades.

Mientras que para diablo explica lo siguiente:

> **¿Quién es el Diablo?**
>
> La palabra "Diablo" se usa para una realidad
> totalmente distinta. En el NT siempre aparece como sustantivo o nombre
> propio y, generalmente, con artículo determinado ("el" Diablo). Se
> trata de una palabra de origen griego (diábolos), que traduce el
> vocablo hebreo Satanás, que significa "el adversario", "el enemigo".  Ambas palabras tienen, pues, el mismo significado.
>
> El plural "diablos", que a veces usamos, es un error. Para la Biblia, sólo
> existe "un" Diablo, como no existe sino un solo "Satanás"...

El texto citado describe que los demonios se "usaban" para describir enfermedades. Los demonios era la causa de cualquier afección inexplicable como por ejemplo que alguien que tenía su boca y su lengua en perfecto estado y era mudo. Tenía que estar "endemoniado".

Luego aparece el siguiente argumento.

> **¿Existen los demonios?**
>
> De acuerdo con nuestros actuales conocimientos
> bíblicos y científicos, no es posible seguir hablando de "posesión
> demoníaca". Este era el lenguaje del tiempo de Jesús. Hoy la medicina
> conoce las causas naturales de la sordomudez, de la epilepsia y de las
> distintas patologías psiquiátricas. No hay por qué recurrir a los
> demonios para explicarlas. En todo caso, no existe base bíblica para
> afirmar la posibilidad de las "posesiones".

Tal vez la anterior es la explicación de porque los demonios fueron desapareciendo del lenguaje mientras el diablo mantuvo su posición.

En párrafos posteriores el documento habla de que hoy la Iglesia continúa hablando del Diablo, pero no del demonio. La Iglesia sigue preocupada por las tentaciones, pero ha ido abandonando el lenguaje de las posesiones. En todos los documentos del Vaticano II sólo tres veces se menciona al demonio y siempre en pasajes bíblicos. El documento de Puebla no lo nombra ni una sola vez. El nuevo Código de Derecho canónico, antes más extenso, reduce el tema del exorcismo a
un solo canon.

Siendo la Iglesia la principal generadora del lenguaje de diablo y demonios, lo anterior explica claramente que no es que la palabra diablo haya ido substituyendo a la palabra demonio sino que la palabra demonio y su significado original fueron cayendo en desuso.

Para terminar cito otro aparte del artículo de la referencia que me parece pertinente aquí:

> **Confusión peligrosa**
>
> Podemos, pues, afirmar que en la Biblia, el Diablo
> o Satanás, al aparecer siempre en singular, en masculino y con
> artículo determinado, se refiere a un ser personal e individual, un
> poder del mal único en su especie. En cambio "demonio", al ir sin
> artículo y ser de género neutro, no se refiere a algo personal. Las
> dos palabras no son sinónimas y no deben considerarse como
> equivalentes. Durante siglos la expresión bíblica "endemoniado" se ha
> tomado lamentablemente como equivalente de "poseído por el Diablo",
> cosa que los Evangelios jamás han afirmado.

Comment: la explicación que traes viene de 1993 lo que podría aplicarse incluso si fuera exclusividad de textos teológicos cristianos, pero en muchas otras religiones se habla de uno o varios demonios que de diablo y aunque Carlos I hablaba 'español con Dios', la iglesia ha venido perdiendo influencia en lo que se escribe... Pero la falla va de mi parte por como formulé la pregunta. (Voy a editarla para ver si me hago entender mejor)